# Ember Upgrade from 3.23 to 3.24 failing at build

Tags: ember.js, upgrade, ember-cli

Was planning to migrate ember application from 3.23 to 3.24. During ember serve the following error is coming:

I have tried upgrading broccoli and babels libs to the latest version. Still the issue persists.

```
ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: TypeError: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/ngcoreui/@ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: path.isStaticBlock is not a function
    at PluginPass.ClassBody (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block/lib/index.js:56:21)
    at newFn (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:177:21)
    at NodePath._call (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:100:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:103:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:77:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:131:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:82:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:108:18)
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/ngcoreui/@ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: path.isStaticBlock is not a function
  - errorMessage: @ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/ngcoreui/@ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: path.isStaticBlock is not a function
        in /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@ember/test-helpers/addon-test-support
        at broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: @ember/test-helpers] (Babel: @ember/test-helpers)
  - errorType: Build Error
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: @ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js
    - line: [undefined]
    - treeDir: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@ember/test-helpers/addon-test-support
  - message: @ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/ngcoreui/@ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: path.isStaticBlock is not a function
        in /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@ember/test-helpers/addon-test-support
        at broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: @ember/test-helpers] (Babel: @ember/test-helpers)
  - name: Error
  - nodeAnnotation: Babel: @ember/test-helpers
  - nodeName: broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: @ember/test-helpers]
  - originalErrorMessage: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/ngcoreui/@ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: path.isStaticBlock is not a function
  - stack: TypeError: /home/abc/dev/sample-ui/ngcoreui/@ember/test-helpers/-internal/debug-info.js: path.isStaticBlock is not a function
    at PluginPass.ClassBody (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block/lib/index.js:56:21)
    at newFn (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:177:21)
    at NodePath._call (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:100:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:103:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:77:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:131:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:82:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/abc/dev/sample-ui/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:108:18)
```

Comment: How did you make an upgrade? via the `ember-cli-update`?

Comment: yes, that is right.. I tried the same to update it to latest version 3.28.4.. same result.

Comment: Just to rule it out try `rm -rf node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm install` to ensure all your dependencies match the changes made in `package.json` by `ember-cli-update`

Comment: was able to overcome the error by updating the @babel/types to a newer version... had missed that somehow as it was in the resolutions...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was resolved in the comments